# CodeSandbox with Material-UI error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_context$muiTheme.borderRadius')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, codesandbox

I am trying to test Material-UI components on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nnxw72j7jl). And keep getting the error:

> TypeError
>   undefined is not an object (evaluating '_context$muiTheme.borderRadius')

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[The solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/l9v5q2548z) was to import this elements from Material UI:

```
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme'
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'
```

And wrap the app with them:

```
render(<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}><App /></MuiThemeProvider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Without them we are not getting any styles from Material UI and without them Material UI cannot work.

This is the correct implementation:
https://codesandbox.io/s/l9v5q2548z